# document.ready is loaded loading after async js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I know that `$(document).ready` is executed immediately after DOM loaded. My question is does it happen before asynchronous JavaScript is loaded? I have scripts which have reference to DOM elements. I want to make sure that before the execution of my scripts all DOM elements and all asynchronous JavaScript are loaded. Note that my script is also loaded asynchronously to the browser end from an external tool. I want to add my scripts into some event handlers. I can not put my scripts in `window.onload` since I have to use the event handler multiple times(appending script/function inside window.onload is also not applicable). 
Basically I want to write event handler which can be used multiple times and will be executed only after DOM and Async scripts are loaded. Can I use `$(document).ready` in this case? Can `$(window).load` be loaded multiple times?

Comment: $(document).ready does not wait for asynchronous code to finish, it does not wait for external resources to load, all it does is wait for the DOM to be ready, i.e. the elements are available.

Comment: OK..$(window).load can be written multiple times? eg: $(window).load( func1(){}); $(window).load(func2(){});

Answer (score 0):

You can use RequireJS (http://requirejs.org/), it ensures your scripts are loaded properly. It's possible to define dependencies needed to run your custom scripts. RequireJS will load them first of all and you'll avoid errors like "xxx is undefined"